# Count No of occurrences in measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have created a measurement (Sales/budget Percentage) that returns the performed output regarding sales/budget. If the percentage output of this measurement is greater or equal to 71% then return 1.

I then need to count the No of occurrences from this measurement that is 1.

I have tried multiple syntax such as Countx, Controws(filter etc. but al of these needs a table and column which I don't provide because it is a measurement.

this is my simple measurement to retrieve a 1 if value is true,

```
   Percentage = sales/budget
   Green = IF([Percentage]>=0,701;1;0)
```

My table is as follows for example

```
     Sales        Budget    (Measurement) Percentage    (Measurement) Green

       100           80       125%                        1

       50            100       50%                        0

       100           100       100%                       1
```

My Measurement which then would count No of occurrences of 1 or 0 in table above would return as below but this I can't seem to figure out.

No 1 = 2

No 0 = 1

How do I do this since my tests with counting above values = IF Above 70% is 1 doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated column using the following DAX:

```
[Above 70% Flag] :=
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE ( DIVIDE ( 'Table'[Sales], 'Table'[Budget] ) )
RETURN
    SWITCH ( TRUE (), Result >= .71, 1, 0 )
```

Then, create your measure referencing your new column:

```
[Count Above 70%] :=
CALCULATE ( COUNT ( [Above 70% Flag] ), [Above 70% Flag] > 0 )
[Count Below 70%] :=
CALCULATE ( COUNT ( [Above 70% Flag] ), [Above 70% Flag] = 0 )
```

Comment: Thanks @StelioK  its alot of measures here but i will try it and get back! its a big modell and all numbers in my table is not from the same table so it gets a bit tricky.